# using javascript to save information locally

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I want to write a greasemonkey script to scrape sites and save data locally, can I use javascript to save the information gathered locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Mozilla's File Object. MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO

**EDIT:** this is easier, but for Chrome only http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: LOL someone didn't like my answer...at least I didn't say ActiveX FileSystemObject!

Comment: Mozilla File I/O is for extensions.  It will not work in Greasemonkey or ordinary JS.  Likewise, HTML5 FileSystem does not work in Greasemonkey -- which is Firefox.  At the most, *part* of this answer might work -- but only in a Chrome userscript, not a Greasemonkey script like the question specified.

Answer (score 4):

[Local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp) is your choice for modern apps!

Comment: is it possible to save or move this data to lets say a text file?

Comment: No, i, actually do not know about such feature. I've used it in web application; and in Chrome you can view data with developers console, but in Firefox...

Comment: You can also use GM_getValue and GM_setValue to store a single variables for a script across multiple pages.

Comment: Is there any way to use local storage to store variables across multiple pages? I normally use GM_setValue and GM_getValue for this purpose, but there might be other options as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
window.location ="data:application/octet-stream," + encodeURI(JSON.stringify(translations.custom));
```

This is how a Pixiv translation script saves custom added translations (which aren't hardcoded into it). You simply get a filesave dialog like you've clicked a directlink.

Translations.custom is just an object in JSON format (var a = {b : 1};).

I have no idea how you'd have to format your data though if it's not in JSON but you can experiment around with that I guess.

An alternative approach would be replacing the whole document's html and just do save page then.

Comment: +1, this actually works (with `encodeURI(sometext)` for text), although there's a annoying lack of default filename.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using JQuery' [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method, as it provides cross platform support and it doesn't have a clear-cut limit to the amount of information you can store.

> Behind the Scenes
>
> Internally, jQuery creates an empty object (called $.cache for the
>   curious), which is used to store the values you set via the data
>   method. Each DOM element you add data to, is assigned a unique ID
>   which is used as a key in the $.cache object. jQuery does not store
>   only user-created data in that cache. It also stores internal
>   information and the event handling functions that you attach with
>   live(), bind() and delegate(). Having centralized data storage makes
>   jQuery’s codebase much more robust and bug free, something that we all
>   can benefit from.

Reference: [jQuery’s Data Method – How and Why to Use It](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/11/jquery-data-method/)

Comment: The `data` method does not "save" information like the OP wants.  Such data is lost when the page closes or reloads.

Comment: Of course, but using Javascript alone that's always the case.

Answer (score 2):

java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.webkit.CookieManager

or you could use this kind of logic..

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
if (x==c_name)
{
return unescape(y);
}
}
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function checkCookie()
{
  var username=getCookie("username");
  if (username!=null && username!="")
  {
    alert("Welcome again " + username);
   }
 else 
   {
     username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
    if (username!=null && username!="")
     {
       setCookie("username",username,365);
     }
  }
 }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkCookie()">
</body>
</html>
```